# Do iPhones sold in the US support dual physical SIMs?

Tags: iphone, sim

I saw this picture on [Using Dual SIM with two nano-SIM cards](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209086), which suggests recent iPhone models may support two physical SIMs:

[image]

A friend allowed me to play with his new iPhone 12 (bought in the US), but I can't seem to be able to fit another nano SIM in the back of the tray.

Does the US iPhone have a smaller tray? Or is the form factor for iPhone 12 different depending on the market?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says right at the top of the support page you link to

> In **China mainland, Hong Kong, and Macao**, iPhone 12, iPhone 12 Pro, iPhone 12 Pro Max, iPhone 11, iPhone 11 Pro, iPhone 11 Pro Max, iPhone XS Max, and iPhone XR feature Dual SIM with two nano-SIM cards

iPhone 12 models sold in the US support one hardware nano SIM and one software-based eSIM though.

Comment: So...there's just some empty space in the US version of the device, from the single-SIM tray?